# Date Picker filter HTML Table using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, filter

I have the code below which will filter HTML table, I'm having issue with date filter i dont know why it's not working. If i pick 2023 it should only show the 2023 names, if i pick 01/01/1990 for example it should show only rows with that specific date

TABLE

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| John | 01/01/2023 |
| Adam | 06/12/1990 |

I tried the code below and it works perfect for names, numbers and letters but it won't work with date pickers for some reason

HTML

```
        <label for="date">Filter By Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
```

JAVASCRIPT (btw, the date column is **number 3**)

```
            if (document.getElementById('date').checked) {



                var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
                input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
                tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

                // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3]; // change number to any other number to target column for table search
                    if (td) {
                        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The date syntax being returned from the [Input Type Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) is `YYYY-MM-DD` (two digits for days and month). Nothing in that syntax will match what you have. Ultimately you need to convert either your table or the HTML value being returned (see formula `dateFixer_` in first snipped)

Also, it's unclear if you want an exact match or just year. Both solutions below.

### To get Exact Match

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var formField = document.getElementById(x);
  var zValue = formField.value;
  var allTrue = false;
  if (zValue === '') {
    var allTrue = true;
  } else {
    var searchTerm = dateFixer_(zValue);
  }
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
     var txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 || allTrue) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function dateFixer_(dateAsYYYYMMDD) {
  const aYear = dateAsYYYYMMDD.slice(0, 4);
  const aMonth = dateAsYYYYMMDD.slice(5, 7);
  const aDay = dateAsYYYYMMDD.slice(8, 10);
  return `${aMonth}/${aDay}/${aYear}`
}
```

```html
<label for="date">Filter By Date:</label>
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" onchange="myFunction('date')">


<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Nme</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>03/01/2023</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ada</td>
    <td>06/12/1990</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

### To Get Year Match

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var formField = document.getElementById(x);
  var zValue = formField.value;
  var allTrue = false;
  if (zValue === '') {
    var allTrue = true;
  } else {
    var searchTerm = zValue.slice(0,4)
  }
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
     var txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 || allTrue) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="date">Filter By Year:</label>
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" onchange="myFunction('date')">


<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Nme</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>03/01/2023</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ada</td>
    <td>06/12/1990</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```